# Displaying single resource for specific user

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to display a single reservation resource for specific user in an API application when a `get` request is made to this route `localhost:8000/api/user/{user}/reservations/{reservation}` and the user should then be able to view the details of the reservation made.

Tried testing by making a get request to `localhost:8000/api/user/1/reservations/1` but nothing is returned.

Here's the controller method that should be returning the reservation

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Reservation;

...

public function showReservation(User $user, Reservation $reservation)
{
    if (auth()->user() == $user) {

        $reservedProduct = new ReservationResource(Reservation::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('id', $reservation->id)->first());

        return response()->json(['reservation' => $reservedProduct]);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my code doesn't work? Keep in mind that there is actually a reserved product made by this user

Comment: try `dd($reservedProduct)` before returning. if it is still null then the your query is not correct.

Comment: Please show the Route declaration. if nothing is returned probably auth()->user() is not equal to $user. Try auth()->user()->id == $user->id

Comment: did you tryied to return somethig outside the if to make sure the condition is true?

Comment: Please show the Route declaration.

Comment: @dparoli this is the route declaration `Route::get('user/{user}/reservations/{reservation}', 'ReservationController@showReservation')`

Comment: You probably mispelled {reservation} somewhere in your code. Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not compare two eloquent models directly, if you want to check if they are the same model you can check for `id` equality:

```php
if (auth()->user()->id == $user->id)
```

Or even better use the `is()` function:

```php
if (auth()->user()->is($user))
```

You can read more of model comparison in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#comparing-models).

Your controller function is returning nothing because the `if clause` is always `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on comparing models. Using the second option now and getting a different error message `ErrorException: Trying to get property &#039;product&#039; of non-object in file...` looking into that

Comment: So does it solve your original error that was nothing returning?

Comment: Yes it does...thumbs up

Answer (score -1):

Finally resolved it and it turned out the solution was straight forward.

So first I corrected the way I was comparing the `auth()->user()` and `$user`.

Then since I was looking for the a single instance of the reservation whose id was already being passed in the route like this `localhost:8000/api/v1/user/{user}/reservations/{reservation}` I simply had to pass in the reservation in the resource and not query which i was doing.

Solution code is

```
if (auth()->user()->is($user)) {

    $reservedProduct = new ReservationResource($reservation);

    return response()->json(['reservation' => $reservedProduct]);
}
```